# Merge nested objects in JavaScript, and append matching properties in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, merge, grouping

I have an object like this, with nested objects:

```
obj1 = { 
  1: { a:5,b:6,c:7,d:8 },
  2: { a:6,b:9,c:10,d:12,e:1 },
  3: { a:3,b:4,c:9 },
}
```

I want to merge all its nested objects, while grouping in a list the values of properties with the same key.

Desired output:

```
{ 
  a: [5,6,3],  
  b: [6,9,4],  
  c: [7,10,9],  
  d: [8,12],  
  e: [1]
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group array items using object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31688459/group-array-items-using-object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good opportunity to show off the neat javascript spread syntax, Array and Object prototype functions, and destructuring patterns.

```
Object.values(obj1).flatMap(Object.entries).reduce(
  (acc, [k, v]) => ({ ...acc, [k]: [...acc[k]||[], v] }), {})
```

**As simple as this!**

---

### Extended answer

1. [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) takes the values of all properties of an object and makes a list out of them. The rules of iteration are same as [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)
   For example:

   ```
   Object.values(obj1)
   // The result will be:
   [{a:5,b:6,c:7,d:8}, {a:6,b:9,c:10,d:12,e:1}, {a:3,b:4,c:9}]
   ```
2. [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) is similar to `Object.values` above, but it generates a list of `[key, val]` pairs instead, one for each property.
   For example:

   ```
   Object.entries({a:5,b:6,c:7,d:8})
   // The result will be:
   [['a',5], ['b',6], ['c',7], ['d',8]]
   ```
3. [`Array.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) applies the passed function on all elements of an array (just like [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)), but in the end, it [flattens](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) the result. That means, if the result is a list of lists, it returns only one big array with all inner elements.
   For example:

   ```
   Object.values(obj1).flatMap(Object.entries)
   // By passing Object.entries as function,
   // it will extract all the key-value pairs in one big list
   [['a',5],['b',6],['c',7],['d',8], ['a',6],['b',9],['c',10],['d',12],['e',1], ['a',3],['b',4],['c',9]]
   ```
4. The [spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) is a neat feature of javascript, that is used to semantically refer to the enumeration of something.

   - When used in [array literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_array_literals), you can merge and append values together to form a bigger array.
     Like this:

     ```
      o = {a: [5, 6]}

      o.a = [...o.a, 3]     // all elements from o.a, appending 3
      { a:[5, 6, 3] }

      o.d = [...o.d, 8]     // TypeError: o.d is undefined
      o.d = [...o.d||[], 8] // if o.d is undefined, use [], then append 8
      { a:[5, 6, 3], d:[8] }

      // This is useful as a semantic: "append to list or create a new one"
     ```

     [Note 1]: `o.d||[]` works because `undefined` is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) and the logical OR operator `||` [short circuits](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR#short-circuit_evaluation).
   - When the spread syntax is used in [object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals), you can merge objects together or append new properties.
     Like this:

     ```
     o = { 
       ...o,                       // all properties of o
       ...{b:[6,9,4], c:[7,10,9]}, // all properties of the literal
       d: [...o.d||[], 12],        // overriding property d
       ['e']: [1]                  // new property with computed name
     }
     // Result will be:      
     { a:[5,6,3], b:[6,9,4], c:[7,10,9], d:[8,12], e:[1] }
     ```
5. [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) iterates over a list, applying the passed function and accumulating the results. In the end, it returns the accumulated value. The returned value depends on the operation performed by the passed function.
   For example, you can use `reduce` to sum over all elements of an array.

   ```
   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].reduce((acc, curr) => curr + acc, 0)
   // It is the same as (((((0 + 1) + 2) + 3) + 4) + 5)
   15
   ```

   However, you can also use `reduce` to take `[key, val]` pairs from a list and make them properties into an object (like [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isFrozen), but more flexible).
   This snippet below uses a [destructuring pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#destructuring_patterns_with_other_syntaxes) to unpack the `[k, v]` pairs passed as function parameter, and uses `[k]` as [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names).
   See:

   ```
   [['a',5], ['b',6], ['c',7], ['d',8]].reduce(
     (acc, [k, v]) => ({ ...acc, [k]:v }), {})
   // The result will be:
   { a:5, b:6, c:7, d:8 }

   [['a',5], ['b',6], ['a',6]].reduce(
     (acc, [k, v]) => ({ ...acc, [k]:v }), {})
   // Property a is repeated, so it will honor only the last value
   { a:6, b:6 }

   // But if we use the semantic "append or create" mentioned above,
   [['a',5], ['b',6], ['a',6]].reduce(
     (acc, [k, v]) => ({ ...acc, [k]: [...acc[k]||[], v] }), {})
   // The result will be:
   { a:[5,6], b:[6] }
   ```

**Now just bring it all together:**

```
Object.values(obj1).flatMap(Object.entries).reduce(
  (acc, [k, v]) => ({ ...acc, [k]: [...acc[k]||[], v] }), {})

// You can read it as:
// From all entries of the inner-lists of obj1, 
// create one big flat array of [k, v] out of them
// and go adding each one as a property into a new object acc
// grouping the value in lists.

// Final result will be:
{ a:[5,6,3], b:[6,9,4], c:[7,10,9], d:[8,12], e:[1] }
```

Comment: it is nice to see short code however could you please kindly explain or refer so that i can read more into it.

Comment: sure, let me add some edits to the answer

Comment: Thank you very much for this. You really made my concept clear and help me under better.

Answer (score 1):

you can use nested loops:

1. get every object in `obj1`
2. for each of them use another loop over the keys (`a`, `b`, ...)
3. if the key doesn't exist in `output`, create an empty array there
4. add the current value to the array at the matching key in output

```js
let obj1 = {
  1: { a: 5, b: 6, c: 7, d: 8 },
  2: { a: 6, b: 9, c: 10, d: 12, e: 1 },
  3: { a: 3, b: 4, c: 9 },
};
let output = {};

for (let n in obj1) {                  // n is a key in obj1 (1, 2, ...)
  for (key in obj1[n]) {               // key is a key in obj1[n] (a, b, ...)
    output[key] ??= [];                // create an empty array if it doesnt exist already
    output[key].push(obj1[n][key]);    // push the value to the array
  }
}

console.log(output);
```

Comment: You can use the [Logical nullish assignment (??=)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment)

Comment: Above code is not working in my system