# Mapping arrays into object with values as an array

Tags: javascript

I would like to create an object containing all the values from the array first and the values from second as an array of values, assuming that this key references multiple numbers such that given the arrays:

```
first = [3,0,5,3]
second = [1,3,10,5]

my output would be {0: 3, 3: [1,5], 5: 10}
```

This is what I have tried:

```
const newObj = {}
for(let i = 0; i < first.length; i++){
    newObj[first[i]] =  second[i] ? [ second[i] ] : second[i]
}
```

This is what I get:

```
{ '0': [ 3 ], '3': [ 5 ], '5': [ 10 ] }
```

Comment: Can you give us *all* the code you have tried? In your code `ppid` is not defined, and are the arrays of the same length?

Comment: @kelly ppid was a typo, that should be read as first. Yes, we can assume the arrays are of the same length

Comment: You just need to check `newObj[first[i]]` to see if there's something there. If so, make it into an array and add `second[i]` to it; otherwise, set it to `second[i]`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey that's the logic I was trying to build with my ternary. Do you mind adding this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the easiest method to understand as it's just the bare logic written in its entirety.

```
for (let i = 0; i < first.length; i++) {
    if (first[i] in newObj) { // If key exists already
        if (typeof newObj[first[i]] === "number") { // and if it's a number
            newObj[first[i]] = [newObj[first[i]]]; // then we wrap it into an array
        }

        newObj[first[i]].push(second[i]); // add the new number
    } else {
        newObj[first[i]] = second[i]; // if it doesn't exist then add it
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through all the items. You have three conditions for every array element you get. You will try to map it to a key of your new object you are creating and these will be the cases:

1. the key exists and value is already an array. (just push to the value)
2. the key exists and is not an array. (just create an array of two values)
3. the key does not exist. (just add a new key value pair)

```js
const first = [3,0,5,3];
const second = [1,3,10,5];
const ans = {};
first.forEach((curr,index) => {
  if(Array.isArray(ans[curr])){ ans[curr] = [...ans[curr],second[index]];
  }
  else{
   if(ans[curr]){ans[curr] = [ans[curr],second[index]];
   }
   else ans[curr] = second[index];
  }
});

console.log(ans);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would collect all the values into arrays, regardless of how many there are (the `transform` function below does this) — having a data structure with uniform types is more predictable/easier to work with.

Then, in a subsequent step, the single element from the arrays with only one element can be extracted (the `extractSingleArrayElements` function below does this). See comments in the code for explanation:

[Code in TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/PQKhCgAIUgVBDA1gUwM6XgOwwJx-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-9IABhIQBbzwSBCUhCfpg4g8hv5ZoljAQrTeSg7PNV0iRVMKOvCJ4CDCoVDqOyYGeaNEdyEyeRKPud7KzRNVsnRQI0YhoTBiwKcOs0IjxdQPEl57WppHMZlTPUG4TrSibSAAPwAcyWwavuuCNJSMqoFoUx7GBiYOuAsxCKI4hNmg36akh4CgBA0BwEgBhYCQchmJAGjaBBzC9rQGFoRIGCQDBnAcMQ-JGM4TTkBuZFKMOMBCM4HDwAoM5YEQb5EL24KQFo8CsN4QwcE0mDeMgphBBygSUeEA6QBpyBaUUx6oBppBdD0fQDEMBlxCMonCAAyk8pgNIQgKadp6AzImm7GkYpr3I8MJWkc7ybB8OznJAVyBWaIXPEs1ptAAPsl4W2gm+apl+hoBTcwUWqFGVvJA6WvMcXz2k6LoTG6L6BL+vj8FJ-7NAA8nxwiUtpFpoFMm6nPG4F5T+f7elJoa0naTKQDGgHUQQ6w+tmkCLFJFZIYmqFiNgY3YchjVzN66wAMz8D6-AAKz8GdmyasdvYgTGd38DGV2QNdD1HSmEKjKgOJaXQzIOWMExBBSvioPwJZgeAx2OVwnDevEDlKC5MJuTYnlGd5Uxg4DEMWPDx3xK4ShuPaPqLBdkBnYs6yvV92xfYsH21QjKbGMg1LEHYUwAFJOR1ABylLmk8ZIEFMSOcNyTLMsLYsS4l0tTOTZgkxqkBViMPDgEAA)

```js
'use strict';

/**
 * Takes an array of keys and an array of values, and returns an object
 * with values collected in arrays grouped by the keys that match their indexes
 *
 * @param {number[]} keys Array of integer keys
 * @param {number[]} values Array of integer values
 * @returns {Record<string, number[]>}
 */
function transform (keys, values) {
  // Ensure that the lengths of the arrays are the same before proceeding:
  if (keys.length !== values.length) throw new Error('Input lengths differ');
  const result = {};

  for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i += 1) {
    const key = keys[i];
    const value = values[i];
    // Create a refrence to the array of values at the key,
    // first creating and assigning it to the object at the key
    // if it doesn't already exist:
    const array = (result[key] ??= []);
    array.push(value);
  }

  return result;
}

/**
 * Takes an object with array values and returns a shallow copy of the object,
 * replacing any array values that have only one element with the element itself
 *
 * @param {Record<string, number[]>} obj
 * @returns {Record<string, number | number[]>}
 */
function extractSingleArrayElements (obj) {
  const result = {};
  for (const [key, array] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    result[key] = array.length === 1 ? array[0] : array;
  }
  return result;
}

const keys = [3, 0, 5, 3];
const values = [1, 3, 10, 5];

const transformed = transform(keys, values);

const actual = extractSingleArrayElements(transformed);

const expected = {0: 3, 3: [1, 5], 5: 10};

console.log(JSON.stringify(actual) === JSON.stringify(expected)); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my suggestion for it, using [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and [computed property names](https://eloquentcode.com/computed-property-names-in-javascript)

```
first.reduce((o, k, i) => ({ ...o, [k]: [...o[k]||[], second[i]] }), {})
```

```js
first = [3,0,5,3]
second = [1,3,10,5]
output = first.reduce((o, k, i) => ({ ...o, [k]: [...o[k]||[], second[i]] }), {})

console.log(output)
```

You can find detailed explanation on this strategy in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73419719/merge-nested-objects-in-javascript-and-append-matching-properties-in-array/73420289#73420289).