# How to merge 2 Arrays with nested Objects into 1 array without duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I have two arrays of objects like this:

```
const oldArr = [
  { 'Tomorrow': [{ id: 2 }, { id: 4 }, { id: 3 }] }, 
  { 'Saturday': [{ id: 2 }, { id: 4 }, { id: 3 }] }
]

const newArr = [
  { 'Monday': [{ id: 2 },{ id: 4},{ id: 3 }] }, 
  { 'Tomorrow': [{ id: 1 },{ id: 5 }]}
]
```

I want to merge both without any duplicate keys, so it should result in:

```
[
  { 'Tomorrow': [{ id: 2 }, { id: 4 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 1 }, { id: 5 }] }, 
  { 'Saturday': [{ id: 2 }, { id: 4 }, { id: 3 }] },
  { 'Monday': [{ id: 2 }, { id: 4 }, { id: 3 }] } 
]
```

As you can see, the contents of `Tomorrow` have been added to the original `Tomorrow`, and the object of `Monday` has been added on.

I've vaguely figured out how to do so with nested loops, but I'm guessing there is a simpler solution using `map`, `reduce`, or the like.

Comment: Please share your reference solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by iterating the combined arrays to generate an object with all the values for each key in the arrays; then using `Object.entries` to map that back to the original format:

```js
const oldArr = [
  {'Tomorrow': [{'id':2},{'id':4},{'id':3}]}, 
  {'Saturday': [{'id':2},{'id':4},{'id':3}]}
]

const newArr = [
  {'Monday': [{'id':2},{'id':4},{'id': 3}]}, 
  {'Tomorrow': [{'id':1},{'id':5}]}
]

const result = Object.entries(oldArr.concat(newArr)
  .reduce((a, o) => {
    let k = Object.keys(o)[0]
    a[k] = (a[k] || []).concat(o[k])
    return a
  }, {})
).map(([k, v]) => ({ [k] : v}))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Works a treat! Very smart

Answer (score 2):

This can be easily accomplished with a combination of the neat javascript spread syntax, Array and Object prototype functions, and destructuring patterns.

```
[...oldArr, ...newArr].flatMap(Object.entries).reduce(
  (acc, [k, v]) => ({ ...acc, [k]: [...acc[k]||[], ...v] }), {})
```

**As simple as this!**

```js
const oldArr = [
  {'Tomorrow': [{'id':2},{'id':4},{'id':3}]}, 
  {'Saturday': [{'id':2},{'id':4},{'id':3}]}
]

const newArr = [
  {'Monday': [{'id':2},{'id':4},{'id': 3}]}, 
  {'Tomorrow': [{'id':1},{'id':5}]}
]

const result = [...oldArr, ...newArr].flatMap(Object.entries).reduce(
  (acc, [k, v]) => ({ ...acc, [k]: [...acc[k]||[], ...v] }), {})
  
console.log(result)
```

---

For a very detailed explanation of how this works, refer to [this extended answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73420289/2938526) to a similar question.  The difference in that other question is that there, each inner object had only one object as a value, instead of an array.

Comment: Hadn’t used flatmap before, clever solution, i noticed the output is an object of objects instead of an array of objects but can be easily tweaked